# Refused to connect to 'ws://localhost:8080/ws' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'

Tags: javascript, websocket, meta-tags

I am trying to open a WebSocket connection from the Binance platform and connect it to a local server.
for example:

```js
// in console

var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws");
 
socket.onopen = function() {};

socket.onmessage = function(e){console.log(e.data);

secket.send("hello")
```

**outpu: form binans:**

**Refused to connect to 'ws://localhost:8080/ws' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' **

**output from else**: hello (The server returns the same message)

I can open this connection from any website (ex: YouTube, Wikipedia, google ...). But I can't do the same on the Bananas platform and get this error.